# PostgreSQL speed up search by email column

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I have table in PostgreSQL database with near to 60 milions records. Table has column email_id defined as

```
character varying(64)
```

I'm trying to optimize searches by this colum. For e.g., query:

```
select count(1) from my_table where email_id = 'some@email.com';
```

takes ~190 seconds to finish and return results. I tried to create index on that column like:

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_idx_email_id
  ON my_table
  USING btree
  (email_id);
```

but there is no significant improvement or even improvement at all. I tried also to analyze queries with explain analyze statement and confirmed that the problem is in email colum.

1. Probably one way to improve case would be to have table customers and in my_table integer foreign key to customers. Currently this is not possible or hard to achieve, since customers are in different database. I'm trying to find other possibilities.
2. I could change email_id colum data type. Could changing to something more appropriate speed up queries?
3. Should i use any other index or maybe some kind of full text search with LIKE 'email'?

Example output of explain analyze:

```
explain analyze select count(1) from my_table where email_id = 'test@unknown.email';
                                                           QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=5211284.25..5211284.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=225424.749..225424.749 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..5211235.72 rows=19410 width=0) (actual time=225424.744..225424.744 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: ((email_id)::text = 'test@unknown.email'::text)
 Total runtime: 225426.646 ms
```

Explain analyze output after enable_seqscan = off:

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
explain analyze select count(1) from my_table where email_id = 'test@unknown.email';
                                                                  QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=10005215244.40..10005215244.41 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=282110.404..282110.405 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=10000000000.00..10005215195.84 rows=19425 width=0) (actual time=282110.393..282110.393 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: ((email_id)::text = 'test@unknown.email'::text)
 Total runtime: 282113.296 ms
```

Comment: what's the output of explain analyze?

Comment: Updated my question with output.

Comment: And what plan do you get with `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`?

Comment: updated with output after enable_seqscan. still slow...

Comment: It looks like you don't have any index on that table that can be used, yet you provided code for the index that should be used in in the second query. How come?

Comment: What do you mean with "that should be used in second query"? Could we force use of index in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Dario Please use @ when replying or I won't be notified about your comment. We can't really force the use of any particular index but the previous command set's the cost of seq_scan to absurdly high so pg will try to use anything other than seq_scan, including indexes that are far from optimal. Here there seems there is no alternative so what happened to the index?

Comment: @JakubKania i don't know what happened. I created index as mentioned. Is this not proper way for my case? Also could be problem that data is too much scattered physically and then maybe some index clustering would help?

Comment: @Dario If everything is correct in your query an index should be used with seqscan disabled. Ensure the index does in fact exists and do append the complete schema of the table including all the indexes.

Comment: What is the output of  `\d+ my_table` in psql?